# What are the different scenarios where Kafka Broker tries to elect a leader for a partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to list out all the different scenarios where Kafka does a leader election. So far, as per my research, a leader election is done when a node goes down. The partitions which were present in the node that went down requires new leaders and hence leader election happens. Are there any other scenario's where leader election occurs?

I'm trying this to reproduce `NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION` exception which I believe occurs when Kafka  pushes to a broker which is not the leader for a partition which I believe is due to outdated metadata in the Producer which can be caused by a Leader Election and hence my efforts to reproduce it.

I tried publishing and stopping a VM with broker in it, but haven't been able to replicate it yet.

Comment: Kafka has scripts called `kafka-preferred-replica-election` and `kafka-reassign-partitions`. Haven't used them much, but those are cases where you can manually force it. One way to get the error, though would be to swap DNS entries for brokers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your finding is correct. Basically, a Leader election happens when a node goes down in the Kafka cluster(which should be a leader). But it is not the only time the leader election happens. Following are other scenarios in leader election happens:

1. When a new partition is added
2. When a leader for a partition becomes unavailable
3. Migration of partition to a different node

Coming to the NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION exception, in order to replicate that exception you can bring down your leader partition and send the data. But you have to make sure that your metadata has that node's information as the leader. Just to give a little bit more insight into this, the Client fetches the metadata before sending the data (it may not be the same all the time, metadata caching can happen). So you should make sure the metadata that the client has the information of the old leader/non-leader node, instead of a new leader.

In short, You can use any of the above-mentioned scenarios to produce NotLeaderForPartition exception. But the only criterion is your client needs to send data to a non-leader node.

Comment: I tried bringing down a single node which I knew was the master for some partitions, but I didn't see the exception logged.

Comment: @RSriram As i said, not just bringing down the node will create this exception. Your client needs to send data to a non-leader. Client gets metadata before it tries to send data , which contains the leader info, but it won't fetch the metadata all the time instead it caches the data. So you have to make sure your client is using this stale metadata